# flutter gradle exited abnormally (firebase authentication)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter

Im trying firebase authentication with my flutter app.

- Registered My app on firebase .
- copied googleservices.json in the app directory.
- copied the dependencies as firebase instructed.

Trying to test my app prior to code(on my android phone connected via USB.), and the following error shows up:

**Shell:**

```
Initializing gradle...                                       3.6s

Resolving dependencies...

* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Volumes/data/Developoment/apps/firebase_pangey/android/gradlew"
exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Volumes/data/Developoment/apps/firebase_pangey/android/app/build.gradle' line:
62
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1] on
project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: /Volumes/data/Developoment/apps/firebase_pangey/android/gradlew app:properties
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

**Pubspec.yaml File**

```
name: firebase_pangey
description: A new Flutter proj
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase_core: ^0.3.0+1
  firebase_analytics: ^2.0.1

  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1

  rxdart: ^0.20.0

dev_dependencies:
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in the google service version. just replace it to

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
```

in `build.grade` project level and then try.